# Работа с многомерными массивами

Tags: c++, матрицы, borland-c++

Cреда Borland C++ Builder - Console App

```
int main()
{
    int* i, *n, *idx;
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int** A = new int* [*n];

    for (*i = 0; *i < *n; *i++)
    {
        A[*i] = new int [*n];
    }

    A[3][3] = 100;
    printf("%d", A[3][3]);

    for (*i = 0; *i < *n; *i++)
        delete[] A[*i];

    delete[] A;
}
```

После ввода размерности программа дальше не выполняется. Ошибок не выдает, просто не выполняется дальше.

Comment: отличный код )))

Comment: *(Попробую задать несколько наводящих вопросов)*

- Вы ведь расставили "звездочки, чтобы компилятор не ругался", правда? :)

- Какую семантику имеют выражения вида `int *i` и `&a`? Как определить тип выражения `&a`, если известен первоначальный тип `a`?

- Какое значение будет иметь переменная `int a;` сразу после ее инициализации? Каким будет ответ на прошлый вопрос, если речь будет идти о выражении `int *a;`?

Comment: Звездочкой промахнулся перед квадратной скобкой надо поставить ее. Так она пытается выделить из хипа количество памяти равное тому что лежит по адресу равному  n за одну итерацию цикла. Вот черт пока я писал ответ привалило еще десяток звездочек, тс явно запутался в редакторе, дублируйте для экранирования метасимволов

Comment: Как я понимаю -  индекс не надо было инициализировать как указатель. Исправил на int i и убрал * перед всеми i. А не работало, потому что я выводил A[3][3] при размерности матрицы 2 или 3. Теперь все работает. Насчет правильности выделения памяти, надо подумать. Начерчу стек и кучу на листке и буду думать)

Comment: Еще представлять матрицу в виде двухмерного динамического массива это плохая идея. Испоьзуйте одномерный массив в стэке. Для перевода индекса в ij  используйте хэш таблицу если хотите работать с большими размерностями.

Comment: То есть использовать одномерный массив, инициализировав его как int \*A[n\*n] и для работы с элементами использовать рабочий указатель?

Comment: Вычисляйте так 

    int 
    getij (int a[], int columns, int row, int column) 
    {
        // a[i][j] для int a[rows][columns]
        return a[row*columns + column];
    }

Comment: Вот исправил код.
<pre class="prettyprint">
 int i,j;
 int *n;  n = new int;
 int *idx;  idx = new int;
 int *idy;  idy = new int;
 printf("Enter n: ");
 scanf("%d",n);
 int *A;
 A = new int [(*n)*(*n)];
 for(idx = A, i=0; idx < A+(*n)*(*n); idx+=(*n), i++)
 {
  for(idy = idx, j=0; idy < idx+*n; idy++, j++)
    {
        printf("A[%d][%d]=",i,j);
        scanf("%d",idx);
    }
  printf("\n\n");
  }
 delete[] A;
</pre>

Comment: @palkanov-vi, код Ваш толком не виден, но зачем так много new?

Вам нужна матрица N\*N ?

    main (int ac, char *av[])
    {
        int n = av[1]? atoi(av[1]): 10; // берем размер из аргументов
        if (n < 2) n = 2;
        int matrix1[n*n]; // эта в стеке (не знаю позволяет ли Borland )
        int *matrix2 = new int [n*n]; // эта в куче
        .....
    }

Как обращаться к элементам [i][j] я описал ранее. На практике лучше, естественно, функцию не вызывать, а вычислять элемент по месту

    matrix1[n*i + j] = 100;
    matrix2[n*5 + 2] = ....

Как то так.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает)А насчет того, что много операторов new, так по заданию все массивы должны быть динамически описаны с помощью new. К тому же и интовские указатели надо через new описывать.

Comment: Согласен с уважаемым @Gorets. Но чем особенно хорош данный код? А тем, что там во множестве звезд легко различима Большая Медведица и, соответственно, направление на север, где и должен располагаться долгожданный RETURN.

Comment: @avp,

    int n = av[1]? atoi(av[1]): 10; // n берем размер из аргументов
    ...
    int matrix1[n*n]; // эта в стеке (не знаю позволяет ли Borland)   

Так не позволит не только компилятор от Borland, но и любой другой уважающий себя компилятор C++, т.к. размер массива хранящегося в стеке должен быть известен ещё ДО компиляции. 
Ну и к тому же, эта проверка на то, был ли передан параметр программе тоже неверная, ибо для этого нужно проверять аргумент `ac`:

    if ac > 1 { ...

Comment: @delphist007, видимо g++ себя не уважает (допускаю, что это такая же нестандартная гнусная (в смысле от GNU) фича, как и адреса меток (например)), да и фиг с ним... 

Список аргументов main() (в нормальных вызовах) положено завершать NULL. Если не доверяете, то ac тоже не панацея.

Comment: @avp ну гнусные расширения -- есть гнусные расширения.

Answer (score 3):

[@delphist007](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/8287/delphist007)

- В `C99` есть [`Variable Length Arrays:`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)

> **6.7.5.2 Array declarators**
>
> If the size is an expression that is **not an integer constant expression:** if it occurs in a
>   declaration at function prototype scope, it is treated as if it were replaced by `*`; otherwise,
>   each time it is evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero. The size of each instance
>   of a variable length array type does not change during its lifetime. Where a size
>   expression is part of the operand of a sizeof operator and changing the value of the
>   size expression would not affect the result of the operator, it is unspeciﬁed whether or not
>   the size expression is evaluated.

- В `gcc` в режиме `C90` они [поддерживаются с помощью `extension'a.`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)
- И да, [их выкинули из `C++11`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.std.c++/K_4lgA1JYeg) в силу наличия в последнем `std::array<T, N>.`

Comment: Круто. А я стандарт по C99 заглянуть поленился.